# Tensorflow exp limit to max instead of infinity?

Tags: tensorflow

A loss function i'm using has an exp term in it which blows up the loss to infinity, which then causes the gradients to go tto NaNs.... is there a way to currently handle this?

```
s = tf.exp(n)  
# s becomes nan when n is large
```

Answer (score 0):

Exponential terms in loss functions are usually handled in machine learning by minimising not the exponential itself, but its logarithm. Both functions are monotonically crescent, so minimising the logarithm brings you to the same minimum than minimising the exponential. However, the logarithm grows much slower, avoiding huge increases in your loss function.

Here it seems that you need to minimize directly on `n` but probably it is only an example.

Comment: ok makes sense... maybe I just have a bug in my implementation? This is the loss i'm trying to minimize: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/23456/is-this-function-the-nce-approximation-for-softmax-is-this-implementation-corre

Comment: sorry, it is now fixed

Answer (score 0):

logit_upper_bound = 88 # because tf.exp(89) yields INF 
s = tf.exp(tf.minimum(n, logit_upper_bound))

Answer (score -1):

For example, you could use this:

`loss = tf.minimum(tf.exp(n), MAX_VALUE)`

this returns the max element wise so you'll need to account for that.

Comment: shouldn't this be tf.minimum(tf.exp(n), MAX_VALUE)?

Comment: You are absolutely right @xela haha thanks for that.